# Enterprise iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

I am developing an in-house app and apple rejected the app, as it is not public. Now, I have to enrol for Enterprise Program.I want to know that after enrolment to Apple's Enterprise Program, how the application will be installed to the client devices. Will this be published on the app store? or the app should be installed from a separate link (not from app store)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using enterprise account you dont need to publish app on appstore, and the enterprise account even will not provide you option to upload app on appstore.

Using Enterprise account you can share application to any person by creating a .ipa file using enterprise credentials. At this point, i am considering you know creating .ipa file using apple account. You dont need to add any device UDID at developer account for installing application.

Comment: Thanks for the details

Answer (score 1):

Read this [Choosing a Membership & Benefits and Resources](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/).It explains clearly.You can see Enterprise program enrollment can deploy app  In-house App Distribution not App Store Distribution.

> Enroll in the Apple Developer Enterprise Program only if you intend to
>   distribute proprietary apps to employees within your organization. If
>   you intend to distribute apps outside of your organization through the
>   App Store, enroll in the Apple Developer Program.

Apple Developer Enterprise Program. If your organization is looking to create proprietary apps designed and distributed exclusively to your organization's employees, enroll in the Apple Developer Enterprise Program. Membership includes access to beta OS releases, advanced app capabilities, and tools needed to develop, test, and distribute apps for your entire development team. Companies and educational institutions must provide a D-U-N-S Number (available for free) registered to their legal entity during the enrollment process.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the details

Comment: @iBug glad to help.